# issue in finding correlation in R

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to find `correlation` between two separate data sets in `R`. The structure of my first data set is (when used `print(matr1)` in `R`):

```
        year  month  income  
 [1,]  "2000" "01"  "30000"
 [2,]  "2000" "02"  "12364"
 [3,]  "2000" "03"  "37485"
 [4,]  "2000" "04"  "2000"
 [5,]  "2000" "05"  "7573"
```

The structure of my second data set is(when used `print(matr2)` in `R`):

```
     month_year     value     
 [1,] "Jan 2000" "84737476"
 [2,] "Feb 2000" "39450334"
 [3,] "Mar 2000" "48384943"
 [4,] "Apr 2000" "12345678"
 [5,] "May 2000" "49595340"
```

Now I want to find out the correlation between these two data sets but the issue that I am having is that the format of month and year in both data sets is different. Also when I used R command `cor(matr1[,"income"],matr2[,"value"])` I got the error as

```
Error in cor(matr1[,"income"],matr2[,"value"]) : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

So, my question is:

1. How to remove the error?
2. How to find the correlation when format of month and year is different?

Any guidance will be helpful for me as I am new to this.

Comment: This is a programming problem rather than a statistical one, and it has been answered many times before on Stack Overflow. Your variables are stored as a `character`, they should be converted to a `numeric` with `as.numeric`.

Comment: ok. So I will post this question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That's probably not a good idea. The question will likely be closed. Additionally, I told you how to do it in my comment: cor(as.numeric(matr1[,"income"])....)

Comment: This question has a reproducible example, so I don't think it will be closed on SO. Please don't cross-post, though, @JasonDonnald. We should be able to migrate your Q to SO for you.

Comment: Just a note about matrices: There cannot be both character and numeric columns in the same matrix.  They have to all be a single class, which is I think why you're having trouble with this. If there are any character values in the matrix, the whole matrix will be converted to `character` values. Try converting to `data.frame`s if this is a big issue.

Comment: +1 for @gungs wonderful suggestion and answer too

Answer (score 2):

Working with dates is kind of a pain, IMO.  But if you already know that your rows correspond (that is, the `income` in row i of `matr1` goes with / is for the same month and year as the `value` in the same row of `matr2`), you can get a correlation quite simply with:

```
cor(as.numeric(matr1[,"income"]), as.numeric(matr2[,"value"]))
```